# Get pagination's last page value with php file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I am looking a way to the find the last value of pagination of an external website. With using get_file_contents I am getting the following result but how can I get the the value "9" just before the Next

```
DOMElement Object ( [tagName] => ul 
[schemaTypeInfo] => [nodeName] => ul 
[nodeValue] => Prev 1 2 3 4 .. 9 Next 
[nodeType] => 1 [parentNode] => (object value omitted) 
[childNodes] => (object value omitted) 
[firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) 
[previousSibling] => [attributes] => (object value omitted) 
[ownerDocument] => (object value omitted) 
[namespaceURI] => [prefix] => [localName] => ul [baseURI] => 
[textContent] => Prev 1 2 3 4 .. 9 Next )
```

Comment: You may want to do some searching on text manipulation in PHP to get you started on this.

Comment: If there is always a `Next` at the end of the string, you might want to `preg_match()` with the following RegExp :

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would first split the textContent with spaces. Then the answer will be [Next Key - 1].

```
$textContent = " Prev 1 2 3 4 .. 9 10 Next ";
$arr = explode(' ', $textContent);

if ($key = array_search('Next', $arr)) {
echo $arr[$key - 1];  
}
// output : 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a `Next` at the end of the string, you might want to `preg_match()` with the following RegExp : `([0-9]+) Next` on `nodeValue` key like this :

```
$found = preg_match("#([0-9]+) Next#", $domElement['nodeValue'], $matches)
```

Then `if ($found) {}` check what's in `$matches[1]`